# Airflow Sensor in reschedule mode: Best practice to store a counter state between pokes?

Tags: airflow

I want to store the state of a counter between pokes in a long running sensor using reschedule mode.

## Problem:

I expect files to be uploaded to a GCS path but do not have a success signal for when all the files have arrived. As a heuristic, to identify the end of an upload session I will consider the data complete if `n * grace_period` minutes have passed without a change in the number of file with that prefix.

## Approach:

I am trying to implement a custom sensor to achieve the following:
- Poke every `n` minutes to see how many files are in GCS with a certain prefix and store this value in `num_files`.

- If `num_files` is not changing since the last poke increment a counter `consecutive_same_pokes`.
- Succeed if `consecutive_same_pokes > grace_period and num_files > min_files`.
- SLA miss if no success in `n * grace_period + 1` minutes.
- Keep poking until `deadline` and succeed if `num_files > min_files`.
  In this case `deadline` will be 24 hours after the start time, hence making reschedule mode necessary for the sensor.

## Core Question:

What is the best practice to store state for `num_files` and `consecutive_same_pokes`?

- Variables: It seems like we will update this state too frequently and only reading this state from the `task_instance` for this sensor.
- XComms: I'm not sure if I can use XComms for intratask communication, as it is intended for intertask communication.
- As a property of my sensor: I am not sure if my state will persist across pokes if store in `MyCustomSensor.num_files` and `MyCustomSensor.consecutive_same_pokes`. Would reschedule mode cause my task to reinitialize each time wiping out counters or does it just reschedule the poke?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a silly suggestion, but rather than using some sort of storage, can't you look at the difference between current time and time of last file upload?